# Ignore case Map.get() type script

Tags: typescript

Can I somehow ignore case when looking for a key in a type script MAP?
I didn't see any overload option to the Map.get() method or anything similar.
Looking for a creative idea.

Comment: Store all keys in lowercase from the start?

Comment: The creation is encapsulated for me.

Answer (score 1):

The js `Map` doesn't support that natively, but you can do it yourself, for example:

```
class IgnoreCaseMap<V> extends Map<string, V> {
    set(key: string, value: V) {
        return super.set(key.toLocaleLowerCase(), value);
    }

    get(key: string): V {
        return super.get(key.toLocaleLowerCase());
    }
}

let map = new IgnoreCaseMap<string>();
map.set("STRING1", "value 1");
map.set("strIng2", "value 2");

console.log(map.get("string1")); // value 1
console.log(map.get("STRING2")); // value 2
```